# Calling AngularJS function from a remote page loaded by Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap 3 modal component to load a remote form, in which I define an Angular controller and several functions. But the browser said "Tried to Load Angular More Than Once".

#### Main page:

```
(omitted: ng-app="manageAppCollections", ng-controller="manageAppController")

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-href="./appConfForm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#saveModal">Add an App</button>

<div id="saveModal" class="modal inmodal fade" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" refresh-modal>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Form page(./appConfForm):

```
<div ng-app="saveForm" ng-controller="saveFormController">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" name="eventEditForm">
            (omitted form content)
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click='addApp()'>Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    angular.module('saveForm',[]).controller('saveFormController', ['$scope, $http', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.addApp = function(){
            console.log("Added!");
        }
    }])
</script>
```

The `addType()` function cannot be triggered.

Do I need to compile the remote content? And how can I do that?

### Edit

Previously I loaded AngularJS files in both pages, which was not necessary. Now I remove those files in the form page, but the content in the page won't work. I assume it needs compiling after loaded, so now:

#### Main page:

```
(omitted: ng-app="manageAppCollections", ng-controller="manageAppController")

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-href="./appConfForm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#saveModal">Add an App</button>

<div id="saveModal" class="modal inmodal fade" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" refresh-modal>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
angular.module('manageAppCollections').directive("refreshModal", ['$compile', function($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on('loaded.bs.modal', function(e) {
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            element.removeData('bs.modal');
        });
    }
}
```

}])

But now the error becomes: `Argument 'saveFormController' is not a function, got undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create two 'ng-app'.

With only two controllers but with the same ng-app, you can do the job.

Can you try something like this : (EDIT: the code bellow doesn't works)

```
<div ng-controller="saveFormController">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" name="eventEditForm">
            (omitted form content)
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click='addApp()'>Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
angular.module('manageAppCollections').controller('saveFormController', ['$scope, $http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.addApp = function(){
      console.log("Added!");
    }
}])
```

**saveFormController** becomes a controller of the **manageAppCollections** app

**EDIT**

To work with AngularJS and Bootrap, you could also use angular-ui, it's easier : http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

**EDIT2**

I edited my previous code, you can check the result here :

## [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/AF6ZSaGHuhYMXMmXJRoS?p=preview)

(from the doc)

Comment: Still, `WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.`

Comment: Do I need to load angularjs files in that form page? I currently load angularjs files in both pages. But if I didn't load those files in the form page, the loaded content cannot work. It seems that I need to compile it first...

Comment: This is not really a 'new' page, this is only the template of your modal wich is loaded from the main page (who contains the angular lib)

Comment: Did some edits too on my plunkr, can you check and tell me if it's good for you ? :)

Comment: Thanks so much it works, but one frustrating thing is that the project doesn't use `'ui.bootstrap'` for some reasons. I ended up moving the controller in the form page to the main page and it somehow worked. Thanks again!