# Angularjs + bootstrap remote modal window not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

If I am doing this its because I couldn't find a real solution yet.

---

> I have this guy similar problem:
>   [Calling AngularJS function from a remote page loaded by Bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839247/)
>
> his "solution" was:
>
> > *Thanks so much it works, but one frustrating thing is that the project doesn't use 'ui.bootstrap' for some reasons. I ended up moving
> >     the controller in the form page to the main page and it somehow
> >     worked.*

Of course I've tried the solution above and its not working for me...

the problem is that *angular* is just not working inside the remote modal, I'm such a newbie and I don't know why this happens

---

I have something like this:

**index.php** (only relevant code of course)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
var users = angular.module('newapp',['ngFlag']);

users.controller('modaluserCTRL', function($scope,$http,$timeout){

console.log("testing1");

    $scope.sendcomment = function (){
        $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'myfunctions.php?test='abc
        }).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log("send!");
        }).catch(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
    }


});
</script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a href="userinfo_modal.php?user={{X.userid}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary" >
  User info!
</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

     <!-- remote info loads here -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**userinfo_modal.php**

```
<?php
 // PHP FUNCTIONS HERE
?>

<div ng-controller="modaluserCTRL">
     <div class="modal-header">
       <?php user_header_info(); ?>
     </div>

      <div class="modal-body" ng-show="managerid==managerREALid">
       <?php user_BODY_info(); ?>

      <button ng-click="showmore = !showmore "> see more...</button>

      <div ng-hide="showmore">
         <?php user_MORE_info(); ?>

         <input type="text" ng-model="usercomment_model" class="form-control" id="comment1">
         <button ng-click="sendcomment()">SEND</button>

      </div>

      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
      </div>
</div>
```

---

Everything in my project is working fine with angular except the remote modal which is the only problem. Thank you in advance (and sorry about my english :P )

Comment: I don't want to be nitpicky but please avoid bold format on the content. It's much cleaner & readable that way. You may use it to segregate the sections though. And don't bother about the English as long as you include enough code for the SO.

Comment: ok thank you this is my first post ( ^_^)